# How to disable button once it is clicked in Discord.js 13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How can I make it so that once a user clicks a button in the message, that button gets disabled whereas the other buttons are still clickable? I'm using Discord.js v13.1.0 and this is what I've been able to write so far:

```js
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require('discord.js');

let row = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
        but_1 = new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('id_1')
            .setLabel('Button 1')
            .setStyle('SECONDARY'),
        but_2 = new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('id_2')
            .setLabel('Button 2')
            .setStyle('SECONDARY')
    );

interaction.reply({ content: "Click a button", components: [row] })
```

I tried creating message component collector to check the id of the button clicked and edit the button but turns out `.addComponents()` just adds another button instead of editing it. This is what I did:

```js
const filter = i => i.customId === 'id_1' && i.user.id === interaction.user.id;

const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });

collector.on('collect', async i => {
    if (i.customId === 'id_1') {
        row.addComponents(
            but_1.setLabel('Click Registered!')
                .setCustomId('id_1_clicked')
                .setDisabled(true)
       )
       interaction.editReply({ content: "Click a button", components: [row] });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

`.addComponents()` will just add to the existing components. Since the components is an array, you need to change `row.components[0].setDisabled(true)` (for but_1) and `row.components[1].setDisabled(true)` (for but_2) and edit the reply with the changed row `MessageActionRow`.

```
collector.on('collect', async i => {
    if (i.customId === 'id_1') {
        row.components[0].setDisabled(true) //disables but_1
    }
    if (i.customId === 'id_2') {
        row.components[1].setDisabled(true) //disables but_2
    }
    interaction.editReply({ content: "Click a button", components: [row] });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. After doing some research, I found that there is a `.spliceComponents()` method for this. But doing by your mentioned way is a lot easier

Comment: @SomeoneLikeMe Can you tell me how you used it? Maybe make a post. I can't find documentation on that. Thanks